# Microsoft Graph API: identify users with provisioning errors

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using Microsoft's Graph API, I am trying to return users with provisioning errors. Using this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesProvisioningErrors,displayName&$filter=onPremisesProvisioningErrors ne null
```

I get back the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-10-04T17:37:29",
            "request-id": "d62be5cf-4f5e-47da-93f1-1bb721bc9b14",
            "client-request-id": "689377a9-469b-bfef-b7d5-d48e7938acec"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to identify just those users with some sort of provisioning error?

Comment: Able to repo the issue from my end , looks like filtering with Null not supported , further investigating ,have you to filter with something else (other than Null ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use any operator to filter users with provisioning errors:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesProvisioningErrors,displayName&$filter=onPremisesProvisioningErrors/any()
```

But it returns the exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Empty any query against property 'onPremisesProvisioningErrors' is not supported.",
        "innerError": {
                      ...
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesprovisioningerror?view=graph-rest-1.0), `onPremisesProvisioningError` resource has property `category` with only one possible value `PropertyConflict`.

I suggest to use filter on that property `category`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesProvisioningErrors,displayName&$filter=onPremisesProvisioningErrors/any(r:r/category eq 'PropertyConflict')
```

It's a little bit workaround but it should return users with provisioning errors.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I cannot test it because there are currently no users with provisioning errors. I am going to mark it as the answer, nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: Figured out a way to induce provisioning errors and confirmed that this worked.